# How to Delete Voicemails from VVM App Using Tasker

Tags: tasker, t-mobile

I have a Tasker program which first seeks out T-Mobile visual voice mail, using root, and then copies them to the internal SD card.  From there, they are auto-synced to a Dropbox account. The copying and syncing work fine, but I'm having trouble deleting the original messages in the /data/data directory.

The problem seems to be that the voice mails can be deleted, but the VVM app still shows them. They show up as voice mails, but with the play button greyed out, implying there's no audio file anymore. The other information, like caller, date, time, and message length, is still observable in the app.

The process for deleting the messages is simply to use a File Delete command within Tasker, again referencing the /data/data/... T-Mobile directory. Trying to delete the entire directory doesn't work.

Is there a way to remove the messages from the VVM app as well? Perhaps by using an intent?

Comment: I see that you have solved the issue by yourself (which is good!), but "*Trying to delete the entire directory doesn't work.*" just curious, I see "Delete File" and "Delete Directory" in Tasker. Did you try both when trying to delete the entire directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting info on the Visual Voice Mail app itself was as simple as deleting the db file. This was located just above the folder containing the voice mails. It was in the format: xxx-xxx-xxxx@tmobile.db.

I used Tasker to delete that file, and then went back into the app. No more voicemail showing.

It's probably best practice to delete the cache files as well.

Haven't had any problems receiving new voicemail. Therefore, there's no reason to try and use an intent to do the same thing. Without the database file, the app can't find any info on deleted voice mail messages, so it thinks they don't exist.